# Play animated gif using easeljs

Tags: javascript, html, gif, createjs, easeljs

I am looking for a way to display animated gifs using the EaselJS/CreateJS library. The only source I find are on displaying an animated spritesheet, but in this case I simply want to show an animated gif instead.

Comment: Did you get the answer? I'm having the same question too.